# Is there a way to render a scene to a video, much faster, using OpenGL instead of EEVEE, without blender unloading geometry?

Tags: rendering, opengl

It seems blender rendering is pretty slow because it doesn't try to do "real time" rendering, it aims at high CGI quality.

Is there a way to configure the renderer to sacrifice quality as much as possible to make rendering much faster? Can I disable ray tracing entirely?

By fast, I mean fast a bit like game 3D engine fast.

I'm guessing blender is not designed this way at all, but I'm still curious to see if it's possible.

Comment: Hi :). You probably already heard of Eevee, Blender's real-time render engine

Comment: In addition to EEVEE, you can use workbench, and limit your materials to very simple diffuse colors.  The workbench render engine is what displays the scene in the 3D Viewport when you are in _Solid_ preview mode, and in fact uses OpenGL to display on the screen.  But @JachymMichal is right, EEVEE is probably what you want.

Comment: I'm already using EEVEE, but it's still pretty slow

Comment: @MartyFouts How do I limit my materials?

Comment: Basically, workbench only supports setting a diffuse color for objects.  It limits the materials itself.